# How to mount a CD/DVD?

Tags: mount, cd

I have a difficulty mounting a cd-rom into a folder.

I tried

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/folder/
mount: /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: /dev/sr0: can't read superblock
```

1. How do I mount it to the folder?

   I can see the cd/dvd creator folder with blank CD-R Disc.
2. Is it possible to share this 'auto mounted blank cd location' with samba share? I know how to configure smb.conf except how to put the path value for this 'auto mounted cd location'.
3. How do I manipulate the auto mounting path and permission?

OS is Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks for reading. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Why would you need to add a 'blank CD' to your samba shares? What exactly are you trying to achieve with that unusual exercise?

Comment: I want to operate the cd-rom in samba server desktop from notebook.

Comment: You can't "operate" the drive remotely via a network share. You can at best mount and share a specific disk. Whenever that disk is changed the share won't work, needs to be unmounted in the client and the new share, if there's one, remounted.

Comment: I have decided not using it. Still want to know things. Anyway it is mounted, automounted. I thought I might change the smb.conf file to share the automounted stuff. Then I connect it from notebook to add files to the automounted thing. Is it too much?